# The limit on subfloor height difference

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I’m about to install a LVP floor over 2 adjacent rooms, one with original hardwood oak floor and the other with 5/8” particle board subfloor. I’d like to have the LVP boards continue from one room to the other with no break. However there is a small height difference between the two floors, ranging from 1/16” to 3/16”. Is this small enough to be absorbed by the LVP attached underlayment or do I need to raise the particle board subfloor to accommodate this ? First time doing this

Comment: Over what length is the height variation? Is the room with the particle board exposed relatively flat (within 1/8 of an inch over 6 feet)?

Answer (score 2):

If there's a 3/16" difference where the two rooms meet, then you'll need to build up that difference before putting down the underlayment. If the difference is spread over the entire floor, no more than 3/16" over an 8' area, you'll be OK.

Since there's a 1/8" difference where the two rooms meet,I'd be real tempted to get a belt sander and slope off that 1/8" difference over 3 or 4 feet before I started ripping up flooring.

Comment: @Scott Hiddelston   I'd be real tempted to get a belt sander and slope off that 1/8" difference  over 3 or 4 feet  before i started ripping up flooring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding a piece of 1/8" plywood (luon) to the low side. Especially if it's a small room. It'd be easier than ripping up the high side.